# Removing the background color from BarChart3D plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to make a 3D bar chart plot with transparent faces on the sides, but for some reason it's very hard to remove them (or to make them transparent at least). I tried looking through the documentation of both [BarChart3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart3D.html) and Graphics3D (which has similar options), but to no avail. Here's a small example that illustrates the problem:

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
BarChart3D[A, ChartLayout -> "Grid", Boxed -> True]
```

And the output:

[image: Simple BarChart3D plot with faces present]

To be clear: I'm attempting to get rid of the two yellowish sides that are at the bottom and back-right here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
BarChart3D[A, ChartLayout -> "Grid", Boxed -> True, Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That is fantastic, thank you!

Comment: This solution is incomplete and produces wrong results. Somehow after the removing the canvas the bars are re-scaled to fill the whole height of the figure. I would like to find a method to remove the canvas without re-scaling the bar heights.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  However, this is not an answer.  If you have a new question, please pose it as such.  Best wishes

Comment: @surfer I have converted your "answer" into a comment.  However it is unlikely that you will get a reply as Dr. belisarius has not been active in some time.  You should [post a new question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you have one.